# Expected number of Intersection of two subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E(h,i,j)$ , $i,j \leq h$, be the expected number of the common numbers of two independently chosen subsets of a set of $h$ elements, where the first and second subsets respectively contain $i$ and $j$ elements($i\leq j$). How to calculate $E(h,i,j)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the number of common elements is $\sum_{k=1}^h X_k$, where $X_k = 1$ if element $k$ is in both subsets and $0$ if it isn't.  Expected value is linear.

Comment: I read in paper it is i*(((h-1)C(j-1))/hCj). But it is obscure how to derive it.

Comment: It is much simpler than that: $h (i/h)(j/h) = ij/h$.

Comment: I am not sure how you calculate it but seems like i and j are independent set in your answer.

Comment: $E(X_k)$ is the probability that $k$ is in both subsets.  
The probability that $k$ is in the first subset (of $i$ randomly chosen elements) is $i/h$.  The probability that it is in the second subset is $j/h$.  We are told that the subsets are chosen independently, so ...